# Extracting data from table on web page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from a table on a web page with beautiful soup. I want to get the data inside the cells for each row.

I am new to python have tried the following snippet, but it's not working:

```
import urllib.request
fname = r"C:\Python34\page.htm"
HtmlFile = open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
source_code = HtmlFile.read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find( "table", {"title":"geoip-demo-results-tbody"} )
rows=list()
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
   rows.append(row)
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    p = col[0].string.strip()
    d = col[1].string.strip()
    print(p)
    print(d)
```

EDIT:Im getting this error 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python34\scrip.py", line 14, in  d = cols[1].text.strip() 
IndexError: list index out of range" for the row 
84.78.229.78ESSantander,
Cantabria,
Cantabria,
Sp‌​ain,
Europe3900143.4647,
-3.8044Orange EspanaOrange Espana 
this is the html file which generated the above error www.pastebin.com/tQ3Cp5Wj thanks

Comment: There are a couple of minor mistakes in the code. Apart from that the major problem is that the data in the table is not in the html source of the page. It is populated from other ajax calls.

Comment: but the data is present in the source of page,im saving this page to the folder and then planning to execute python so that i can get the value for individual rows,so ajax might not be a problem

Comment: Could you please check again that the data is available in the saved source? The table in target is displayed in source as - `<tbody id="geoip-demo-results-tbody" >   </tbody>`

Comment: yeah please check this,its present in the table im saving the webpage after its populated
        http://pastebin.com/FAFijXc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fname = r"F:\Vikas\jobs\temp\page.htm"
HtmlFile = open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
source_code = HtmlFile.read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('tbody', id='geoip-demo-results-tbody')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.find_all('td')
    p = cols[0].text.strip()
    d = cols[1].text.strip()
    print(p)
    print(d)
```

Comment: im getting Index error, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\scrip.py", line 14, in <module>
    d = cols[1].text.strip()
IndexError: list index out of range" for the row <td>84.78.229.78</td><td>ES</td><td>Santander,<br>Cantabria,<br>Cantabria,<br>Spain,<br>Europe</td><td>39001</td><td>43.4647,<br>-3.8044</td><td>Orange Espana</td><td>Orange Espana</td><td></td><td></td>

check this paste for html http://pastebin.com/tQ3Cp5Wj 
thanks

Comment: Please look at the html carefully. There are some rows which do not have more than one, and hence the error for those rows. You will have t handle such scenarios specifically using try/catch blocks.

Comment: oh thanks i thought it was a problem in parsing,used try except for the first time and it worked thanks :-)

Comment: A suggestion, use except only for what is expected rather than using a generic except section. In your scenario, you should just handle `except IndexError`.

Comment: yeah i have used IndexError exception